# ask for about cordova device.uuid javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

ask for about cordova device.uuid javascript ?

Where can i get this dir for use in `cordova.js`

```
cordova/channel
cordova/platform
```

i use this code for main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this for `cordova.js`

```
/*
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 *
*/

// Workaround for Windows 10 in hosted environment case
// http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object
if (window.cordova && !(window.cordova instanceof HTMLElement)) {
    throw new Error("cordova already defined");
}    

var channel = require('cordova/channel');
var platform = require('cordova/platform');    

/**
 * Intercept calls to addEventListener + removeEventListener and handle deviceready,
 * resume, and pause events.
 */
var m_document_addEventListener = document.addEventListener;
var m_document_removeEventListener = document.removeEventListener;
var m_window_addEventListener = window.addEventListener;
var m_window_removeEventListener = window.removeEventListener;

/**
 * Houses custom event handlers to intercept on document + window event listeners.
 */
var documentEventHandlers = {},
    windowEventHandlers = {};

document.addEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    if (typeof documentEventHandlers[e] != 'undefined') {
        documentEventHandlers[e].subscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_document_addEventListener.call(document, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

window.addEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    if (typeof windowEventHandlers[e] != 'undefined') {
        windowEventHandlers[e].subscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_window_addEventListener.call(window, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

document.removeEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    // If unsubscribing from an event that is handled by a plugin
    if (typeof documentEventHandlers[e] != "undefined") {
        documentEventHandlers[e].unsubscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_document_removeEventListener.call(document, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

window.removeEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    // If unsubscribing from an event that is handled by a plugin
    if (typeof windowEventHandlers[e] != "undefined") {
        windowEventHandlers[e].unsubscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_window_removeEventListener.call(window, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

function createEvent(type, data) {
    var event = document.createEvent('Events');
    event.initEvent(type, false, false);
    if (data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                event[i] = data[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return event;
}    

var cordova = {
    define:define,
    require:require,
    version:PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL,
    platformVersion:PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL,
    platformId:platform.id,
    /**
     * Methods to add/remove your own addEventListener hijacking on document + window.
     */
    addWindowEventHandler:function(event) {
        return (windowEventHandlers[event] = channel.create(event));
    },
    addStickyDocumentEventHandler:function(event) {
        return (documentEventHandlers[event] = channel.createSticky(event));
    },
    addDocumentEventHandler:function(event) {
        return (documentEventHandlers[event] = channel.create(event));
    },
    removeWindowEventHandler:function(event) {
        delete windowEventHandlers[event];
    },
    removeDocumentEventHandler:function(event) {
        delete documentEventHandlers[event];
    },
    /**
     * Retrieve original event handlers that were replaced by Cordova
     *
     * @return object
     */
    getOriginalHandlers: function() {
        return {'document': {'addEventListener': m_document_addEventListener, 'removeEventListener': m_document_removeEventListener},
        'window': {'addEventListener': m_window_addEventListener, 'removeEventListener': m_window_removeEventListener}};
    },
    /**
     * Method to fire event from native code
     * bNoDetach is required for events which cause an exception which needs to be caught in native code
     */
    fireDocumentEvent: function(type, data, bNoDetach) {
        var evt = createEvent(type, data);
        if (typeof documentEventHandlers[type] != 'undefined') {
            if( bNoDetach ) {
                documentEventHandlers[type].fire(evt);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Fire deviceready on listeners that were registered before cordova.js was loaded.
                    if (type == 'deviceready') {
                        document.dispatchEvent(evt);
                    }
                    documentEventHandlers[type].fire(evt);
                }, 0);
            }
        } else {
            document.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    },
    fireWindowEvent: function(type, data) {
        var evt = createEvent(type,data);
        if (typeof windowEventHandlers[type] != 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                windowEventHandlers[type].fire(evt);
            }, 0);
        } else {
            window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Plugin callback mechanism.
     */
    // Randomize the starting callbackId to avoid collisions after refreshing or navigating.
    // This way, it's very unlikely that any new callback would get the same callbackId as an old callback.
    callbackId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000000000),
    callbacks:  {},
    callbackStatus: {
        NO_RESULT: 0,
        OK: 1,
        CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION: 2,
        ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION: 3,
        INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION: 4,
        MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION: 5,
        IO_EXCEPTION: 6,
        INVALID_ACTION: 7,
        JSON_EXCEPTION: 8,
        ERROR: 9
    },

    /**
     * Called by native code when returning successful result from an action.
     */
    callbackSuccess: function(callbackId, args) {
        cordova.callbackFromNative(callbackId, true, args.status, [args.message], args.keepCallback);
    },

    /**
     * Called by native code when returning error result from an action.
     */
    callbackError: function(callbackId, args) {
        // TODO: Deprecate callbackSuccess and callbackError in favour of callbackFromNative.
        // Derive success from status.
        cordova.callbackFromNative(callbackId, false, args.status, [args.message], args.keepCallback);
    },

    /**
     * Called by native code when returning the result from an action.
     */
    callbackFromNative: function(callbackId, isSuccess, status, args, keepCallback) {
        try {
            var callback = cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
            if (callback) {
                if (isSuccess && status == cordova.callbackStatus.OK) {
                    callback.success && callback.success.apply(null, args);
                } else if (!isSuccess) {
                    callback.fail && callback.fail.apply(null, args);
                }
                /*
                else
                    Note, this case is intentionally not caught.
                    this can happen if isSuccess is true, but callbackStatus is NO_RESULT
                    which is used to remove a callback from the list without calling the callbacks
                    typically keepCallback is false in this case
                */
                // Clear callback if not expecting any more results
                if (!keepCallback) {
                    delete cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            var msg = "Error in " + (isSuccess ? "Success" : "Error") + " callbackId: " + callbackId + " : " + err;
            console && console.log && console.log(msg);
            cordova.fireWindowEvent("cordovacallbackerror", { 'message': msg });
            throw err;
        }
    },
    addConstructor: function(func) {
        channel.onCordovaReady.subscribe(function() {
            try {
                func();
            } catch(e) {
                console.log("Failed to run constructor: " + e);
            }
        });
    }
};  

module.exports = cordova;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `cordova-plugin-device` first

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

Then you can use `device.uuid` or any other property of device object

Comment: Where to download cordova-plugin-device ?

Comment: The command I wrote 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device' installs the plugin in your project